# Show ${\pm 3^i}, 1\leq i \leq 2^{n-2}$ is reduced residue system mod $2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show  set ${\pm 3^i}$, $1\leq i \leq 2^{n-2}$ is reduced residue system mod $2^n$.

For this, I believe I need to prove that for any integer $a$ such that $gcd(a,2^n)=1$, there exists an element $b$ in the set  ${\pm 3^i}$, $1\leq i \leq 2^{n-2}$ so that $a \equiv b$ mod $2^n$. As part of a problem related to this question, I've managed to show that the order of $3$ modulo $2^n$ is $2^{n-2}$. By the definition of order, this should fulfill the requirement of distinct elements in the given set.

How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct regarding what you need to prove, and have made a good start to determining a solution. Note that since there are $2^{n-1}$ odd integers between $1$ and $2^n$, inclusive, i.e., $\varphi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$, and the set $S = \{\pm 3^{i}, 1 \le i \le 2^{n-2}\}$ has $2(2^{n-2}) = 2^{n-1}$ elements, each of which are odd (i.e., coprime to $2^n$), we only need to prove that each element of $S$ is distinct modulo $2^n$.

To do that, first with $n = 2$, we have $\pm 3$ which is a reduced residue system for $2^2 = 4$. Thus, consider only $n \gt 2$. Using the [$2$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) function, for even integers $m$, we have $3^m \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, so $3^m + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$ giving $\nu_2(3^m + 1) = 1$. With $m$ odd, we have $\nu_2(3^m + 1) = 2$, with this determined by using the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) (LTE lemma) with $3^m - (-1)^m$, or noting that $3^m + 1 = (3 + 1)(\color{blue}{3^{m-1} - 3^{m-2} + \ldots - 3 + 1})$, with the blue part having $m$ (i.e., an odd number) terms, each of which are odd, so their sum is odd. Altogether, this means $\nu_2(3^m + 1) \le 2$.

In addition, as you've noted, plus this can be shown using the LTE lemma and is also explained in [if $3^k \equiv \ 1\pmod{2^n}$ then $2^{n-2} | k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160913/602049), the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $3$ modulo $2^n$ is $2^{n-2}$.

Consider that $2$ distinct elements of $S$ have the same congruence modulo $2^n$. First, with them having the same sign and $1 \le j \lt k \le 2^{n-2}$, we have

$$\pm 3^{j} \equiv \pm 3^{k} \pmod{2^n} \; \to \; 1 \equiv 3^{k-j} \pmod{2^n} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

However, $0 \lt k - j \lt 2^{n-2}$, but the multiplicative order being $2^{n-2}$ means this is impossible.

For the second case, with them having opposite signs and $1 \le j, k \le 2^{n-2}$, we get

$$\pm 3^{j} \equiv \mp 3^{k} \pmod{2^n} \; \to \; 3^{j} + 3^{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

WLOG, have $j \le k$, so \eqref{eq2A} becomes $3^{j}(1 + 3^{k-j}) \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n} \; \to \; 1 + 3^{k-j} \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n}$. This requires $\nu_2(1 + 3^{k-j}) \ge n$, but $n \gt 2$ and, as shown previously, $\nu_2(1 + 3^{k-j}) \le 2$, so this is not possible.

The results of these $2$ cases show that all of the elements of $S$ have distinct congruences modulo $2^n$ so, as explained originally, $S$ forms a reduced residue system mod $2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**I have put in a full proof for completeness.** Claim 2 below says that the order of $3$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^{\ell+2}\mathbb{Z})^*$ is
exactly $2^{\ell}$ as you have noted. It sounds that you have already observed Claim 2 yourself but I included this for anyone else who is interested. Then Claim 3 stated and established below is the crux on how you finish establishing that the stated set is indeed  a reduced residue system. **The Lifting The Exponent Lemma is not needed!**

**THM 1:** *Let $\ell$ be a positive integer. Then the set $\{\pm 3^k;
  k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 2^{\ell}\}\}$ form a reduced residue mod $2^{\ell+2}$.*

We prove THM 1 via Claims 2 and 3 stated below:

**Claim 2:** *Let $\ell$ be a positive integer. Let $r_{\ell}$ be
the smallest positive integer such that the equation
$3^{r_{\ell}}\equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 1$ holds. Then the equation
$r_{\ell} = 2^{\ell}$ holds. Equivalently, for all positives integers $k$ in $\{1,2, \ldots, 2^{\ell}-1\}$, the relation
$3^{k} \not \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 1$ holds.*

*Proof of Claim 2:* We first note the following: First, $r_{\ell}$
must be a power of $2$ [as $|(\mathbb{Z}/2^{\ell'}\mathbb{Z})^*|$ is
a power of $2$, and $3$ is in
$(\mathbb{Z}/2^{\ell'}\mathbb{Z})^*$. Next, $r_{\ell+1} \ge r_{\ell}$
for each positive integer $\ell$. [Indeed, if for any positive
integers $\ell'$ and $r$ the equation $3^r \equiv_{2^{\ell'+1}} 1$
holds, then so does the equation $3^r \equiv_{2^{\ell'}} 1$.] So to
finish the proof of Claim 2, it suffices to do two things:

- (A) First, for each positive integer
  $\ell$, show that the equation $3^{2^{\ell+1}} \equiv_{2^{\ell+3}} 1$ is
  satisfied.
- (B) Next, show that the relation
  $3^{2^{r+1}} \not \equiv_{2^{\ell+4}} 1$ is also satisfied.

However, both (A) and (B) are clearly true for $\ell=1$. Thus, use
induction.  In particular, assume that the equation
$3^{2^{\ell}} \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 1$ holds, as well as the relation
$3^{2^{\ell}} \not \equiv_{2^{\ell+3}} 1$, or equivalently,
$3^{2^{\ell}} \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 1 + C2^{\ell+2}$, for some *odd*
integer $C$. Then these imply:

$$3^{2^{\ell+1}} = (3^{2^{\ell}})^2$$ $$= (1+C2^{\ell+2})^2$$  $$= 1 +[2C + C^22^{\ell+2}]2^{\ell+2}$$
$$ = 1+[C+C^22^{\ell+1}]2^{\ell+3},$$

which gives indeed:

- The equation $3^{2^{r+1}} \equiv_{2^{\ell+3}} 1$ is
  satisfied.
- The relation $3^{2^{r+1}} \not \equiv_{2^{\ell+4}} 1$ is also
  satisfied. [Indeed, $C+C^22^{\ell+1}$ as above is an odd integer.]

Thus, we have done (A) and (B) as above, and as already noted, this
suffices to establish Claim 2. $\surd$

**Claim 3:** *Let $\ell$ be a positive integer. There is no integer
$k \in \{0,1,2, \ldots, 2^{\ell}-1\}$ such that $3^k
 \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} \ -1$ holds.*

*Proof of Claim 3:* If $\ell \le 3$ then this can be checked
directly. Then if there is a
$k \in \{0,1, \ldots, 2^{\ell}-1\}$ such that $3^k \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} \ -1$,
then $k$ must be *positive*, and then both the relation $2k < 2^{\ell+1}$, and the equation $3^{2k} \equiv_{2^{\ell+3}} 1$ hold. This contradicts Claim 2 above. And thus Claim 3 follows. $\surd$

*We now finish the proof of THM 1.* To establish THM 1, it suffices to show both that $3^{k_1} \not \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 3^{k_2}$ for *distinct* integers $k_1,k_2 \in \{1,2, \ldots, 2^{\ell}\}$, and
$3^{k_1} \not \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} -3^{k_2}$ for integers $k_1,k_2 \in \{1,2, \ldots, 2^{\ell}\}$. We do this next.

Let us suppose that there are
distinct integers $k_1,k_2 \in \{1,2, \ldots, 2^{\ell}\}$ such that
$3^{k_1} \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 3^{k_2}$.  Then assuming WLOG $k_1 >
k_2$, this gives the equation $$3^{k_1-k_2} \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} 1.$$
[make sure you see why.] This is impossible via Claim 2 [because $k_1-k_2$ is an integer in $\{1,2,\ldots, 2^{\ell}-1\}$].

Now suppose
that there are integers $k_1,k_2 \in \{1,2, \ldots, 2^{\ell}\}$ such that $3^{k_1} \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} -3^{k_2}$, with $k_1 \ge k_2$. Then this gives the equation $$3^{k_1-k_2} \equiv_{2^{\ell+2}} \ -1.$$ This is
impossible via Claim 3 [because $k_1-k_2$ is an integer in $\{0,1,2,\ldots, 2^{\ell}-1\}$].

Thus as already noted, from this THM 1 follows.